# Only last stored data returned from the external file

Tags: python

I have to create a program called 'user_generator' that takes a login as an argument and stores this login in the end of an external file called 'logins.db'.

My problem is : when I use the function 'writelines' into 'logins.db', this file returns only the last input data. This is what I've done :

```
import sys


new_logins = sys.argv[0]
logins = sys.argv[1:]
count = len(logins)

f=open('logins.db','w')
logins=map(lambda x:x+'\n', logins)
f.writelines(logins)

logins = []

with open('logins.db', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        current_login = line[:-1]
        logins.append(current_login)
```

Some people told me to use SQL functions, but I really don't that it's really needed in this case. What do you think ?

Edit : As expected, thanks to you it worked and I could learn more about Python. However, I don't understand the utility of the first line "new_logins = sys.argv[0]", because it worked without it. Can you tell me if it is important for something ? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never closed the file before you opened it again to read it.
You need to use the `close()` function on the file before you reopen it:

```
import sys


new_logins = sys.argv[0]
logins = sys.argv[1:]
count = len(logins)

f=open('logins.db','w')
logins=map(lambda x:x+'\n', logins)
f.writelines(logins)

f.close()

logins = []

with open('logins.db', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        current_login = line[:-1]
        logins.append(current_login)
```

or just use `with` block like you used for reading:

```
import sys


new_logins = sys.argv[0]
logins = sys.argv[1:]
count = len(logins)
logins=map(lambda x:x+'\n', logins)

with open('logins.db', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(logins)

logins = []

with open('logins.db', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        current_login = line[:-1]
        logins.append(current_login)
```

Comment: As expected, thanks to you it worked and I could learn more about Python. However, I don't understand the utility of the first line "new_logins = sys.argv[0]", because it worked without it. Can you tell me if it is important for something ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: First, I am glad I helped you and I will appreciate it if you will accept the answer :) second, no, since you are not using this line, remove it. I didn't notice that it is there. `sys.argv[0]` just return the name of the file. It is useless in your program, no need to save it as `new_logins`, just skip to `sys.argv[1]`.